# EasyAutocomplete buscar solo después de N caracteres

Tags: javascript

quiero saber si existe un parámetro para indicarle a **EasyAutocomplete** que busque solamente las cadenas mayores a 3 caracteres, para que no me haga búsquedas del tipo:

```
?q=1 
?q=12
?q=123 
?q=1234
```

Sino que solamente ejecute la búsqueda cuando hay 4 caracteres o más.

Ya intenté con parámetros como `minChars`, `minLength` pero no funcionan.

```
var options2 = {
        url: route2,
            //Valor que espera encontrar dentro de la colección que va retornar el JSON
            getValue: function(element) {
                return element.telefono1 || element.telefono2 || element.telefono3 || element.celular;
            },
            adjustWidth: false,
            template: {
                type: "custom",
                method: function(value, item) {
                    return item.razon_social;
                }
            },

            list: {

                onSelectItemEvent: function() {
                    var num_cuenta = $("#inputTelefono").getSelectedItemData().id_cuenta;
                    var id_padron = $("#inputTelefono").getSelectedItemData().id_padron;
                    var nombre_cliente = $("#inputTelefono").getSelectedItemData().razon_social;

                    $("#nombre_cliente").val(nombre_cliente).trigger("change");
                    $("#num_cuenta").val(num_cuenta).trigger("change");
                    $("#id_padron").val(id_padron).trigger("change");

                    $("#nombre_cliente_tag1").val(nombre_cliente).trigger("change");
                    var popoverEl = $("#btn_cte");
                    popoverEl.attr("data-content", "Sr(a). <b>"+ nombre_cliente + "</b> ¿Qué tipo de falla es la que desea reportar?");
                    $(".nombre_cliente_span").text(nombre_cliente).trigger("change");
                    $("#nombre_cliente_tag2").val(nombre_cliente).trigger("change");
                    $('#next1').attr('disabled', false);



                },
                maxNumberOfElements: 10,

                match: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },

            ajaxSettings: {
                dataType: "json",
                method: "GET",
                data: {
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },

            preparePostData: function(data) {
                data.q = $("#inputTelefono").val();
                    return data;

            },

            requestDelay: 500
        };
```

Comment: podrias compartir el codigo de implementacion?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo encontré, en el ISSUE 133 del repositorio oficial de github tocan otro tema, pero en el código muestran el parámetro, es **minCharNumber**:

```
minCharNumber: 2,
getValue: function(element) {
                return element.telefono1 || element.telefono2 || element.telefono3 || element.celular;
            }
```

Y como pueden ver se pone antes del parámetro getValue.